# Android Time Picker Format

Tags: java, android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am using `TimePicker` and in picker it showing time in `24 hour` format, which is good, but when i `select` ...

Getting - `9:5 PM`

Requirement 1 - `09:05 PM`

Requirement 2 - `21:05`

```
  case DIALOG_TIME:
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(this, lisTime, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(FormActivity.this));

   .......


    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener lisTime = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String hour = "";
            String meridiem = "";
            Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
            datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

            if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
                meridiem = "AM";
            else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
                meridiem = "PM";

            hour = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":String.valueOf(datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR));
            editTime.setText(hour + ":" + String.valueOf(minute) + " " + meridiem);
        }
    };
```

So where i have to make changes in my code, to get this done !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Requirement 1: use below code:**

```
String date="9:5 PM";

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            Log.e("",""+new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.getDefault()).format(simpleDateFormat.parse(date)));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**For Requirement 2: use below code:**

```
 private String pad(int value){

            if(value<10){
                return "0"+value;
            }


            return ""+value;            
        }
```

**EDITED:**

Replace below lines

```
            editTime.setText(hour + ":" + String.valueOf(minute) + " " + meridiem);
```

to

```
String date=pad(Integer.parseInt(hour)) + ":" + pad(minute) + " " + meridiem;

         SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            editTime.setText(""+new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.getDefault()).format(simpleDateFormat.parse(date)));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: wait. i modifying the solution.

Comment: I edited the solution. if you still any query, please let me know.

Comment: thanks now i am getting result in 24 hours format, but what if i also want result like this: 09:05 PM, using your code getting : 21:05

Comment: then you do not have to convert. the date variable already have the value what you require. Just the date value using log